# Sample code for promoting a transaction using the official IOTA JS Library?

Tags: javascript, promote

Is there a sample publicly available, showing how to use the official IOTA S Library to promote a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [the official wallet app](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/e2a8077745c9d9b37841383b3a2bf03b661f12b6/ui/js/ui.history.js#L285):

```
const spamTransfer = [{address: '9'.repeat(81), value: 0, message: '', tag: ''}]

iota.api.promoteTransaction(transactionHash, 10, 14, spamTransfer,
          {interrupt: false, delay: 0});
```

Documentation [is available here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/#promotetransaction).